# python keyboard - how to deal with multiple keys?

Tags: python, keyboard

Im trying to do a simple bot with using python keyboard lib.

i can send key presses with keyobard.send however if player presses and holds w for movement keyboard.send is not working.

What should i do?

Answer (score 0):

But here you go you need to call the press and release function like this:

```
# press a
keyboard.press("a")
# wait 1 second
time.sleep(1)
# release a
keyboard.release("a")
```